# Returning Hashmap From controller to JSP in Springmvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

I have two dropdownlists in Jsp One for state and other for country. As soon as i select country the statelist should be populated automatically with respective lists. But i am getting whole jsp page as response in ajax call.
My ajax Program:

```
$("select#country").change(function() {
var val=$("#country").val();
alert(val);
$.ajax({
url : 'getstates',
method : 'get',
contentType: 'application/json',
 data :{
          country : val
        },

  success: function (data) {
  alert("Success Response"+ data);

  },

   error :function()
   {
           alert("error");
    }          

   });
```

My controller program

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getstates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView  showstates(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "") 
     String country,@Valid    @ModelAttribute("employee")Login employee, 
     BindingResult result, Model model) {  
    HashMap<String,String>  stateMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
     //put your logic to add state on basis of country

     if (country.equals("UnitedStates")) {
         stateMap.put("Al","Alaska");
         stateMap.put("Tl","Texas");

     } else if (country.equals("UnitedKingdom")) {
         stateMap.put("Be","Bedfordshire");
         stateMap.put("Ber","Berkshire");

     } else if (country.equals("India")) {
         stateMap.put("Mh","Maharashtra");
         stateMap.put("WB","West Bengal");
         stateMap.put("KR","Karnataka");
         stateMap.put("AP","Andhra Pradesh");
         stateMap.put("TN","Tamil Nadu");
     } 


     return new ModelAndView("LoginForm","state" ,stateMap);
 }
```

I am using spring form. I need to get only Staemap as respone but i am getting whole jsp page as response.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get only Staemap as respone but i am getting whole jsp page
>   as response.

Because you are returning the `ModelAndView` object with the view here,

```
return new ModelAndView("LoginForm","state" ,stateMap);
```

If you need to return the `respone` alone from the controller method.However you cant print the `HashMap` directly in the `ajax` response on your jsp. IMHO you can convert it to `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jarray = JSONArray.fromObject(statemap);
```

Read ,

- [send array from controller to a view using JSON in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756675/send-array-from-controller-to-a-view-using-json-in-mvc)
- [Sending JSON response from spring controller](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html)
- [loop through json array jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771616/loop-through-json-array-jquery)

Comment: Thank u.. should i return Json array to jsp? but how to access jarray in jsp?

Comment: Added the examples in my answer. you can't directly access them in jsp , need javascript to do the work in ajax

Comment: I am using spring form and jquery. How to access hashmap in jquery? i mean hashmap is sent as response so how to access and put to dropdown menu?

Comment: I am using spring form and jquery. Should i return only JSONArray from controller? how to access Jsonarray in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RequestMapping(value="LoadBaselineVersions")
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<Integer,String> loadBaseNames(@RequestParam(value="projectname") String name,HttpSession session){

                 return basenameService.getBaselineversions(name);
        }
$("#projectname").bind(
                'blur',
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'post',
                        url : 'LoadBaselineVersions?projectname='
                                + $("#projectname").val(),
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function(data) {
                            $("#baseversion").empty();
                            $.each(data, function(val, text) {

                                $("#baseversion").append(
                                        $('<option></option>').val(text).html(
                                                text));

                            });

                        }
                    });
                });
```